# Linux config system proxy by pac file

Tags: linux, configuration, proxy, pac

Is it possible for me to config system-wide proxy by a .pac file under linux?

I know I could set proxy by

```
export $PROXY=proxyserver:port
```

But I want to implement something like:

```
export $PROXY=~/proxy.pac
```

Maybe I need a local lightweight proxy server, but I cannot find such one, are there any suggestions?

Thanks very much and sorry for my broken English.

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve ? setting your system wide proxy with `.pac` file or you are looking for a proxy server in order to install on your host ?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest my [pacproxy](https://github.com/otahi/pacproxy) if you are familier with Ruby.
After installation, you can use like as follows.

```
$ bundle exec pacproxy -P ~/proxy.pac -p 3128

$ export $PROXY=localhost:3128
```

Comment: It is what I'm searching for. Thanks.